# How to read appsettings.json values ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net

After I've read this article about dependency injection [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/06/19/how-to-read-unable-to-read-appsettings-json-values-asp-net-core/) I still do not have a clear understanding on how to read the appsetting in other than a controller classes.

Lets say for instance I have a helper class with a bunch of static methods that I'm planning to use, I do not create an instance of this class, how do I read setting values to use inside the methods of this class?

Answer (score 2):

I used to create helper class to read data from appsettings.config in one of my applications:

```
public static class ConfigValueProvider
{
    private static readonly IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

    static ConfigValueProvider()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public static string Get(string name)
    {
        return Configuration[name];
    }
}
```

However later I reviewed my application to get away from `static` methods which depends on application config in order to make my application testable.

Comment: How static methods were making it untestible? Also, how do you read nested values with this approach?

Comment: You cannot mock static methods, so you might face issues when trying to test classes which uses static methods internally. For using nesting, you will need to extend static constructor, I have not done it, however you can check source code for asp.net core started app(maybe decompile it)

Comment: One possibility is the extension method

Answer (score 2):

You should use services.Configure as below:

```
   public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
          services.Configure<JSonAsClass>(Configuration.GetSection("MySectionName"));
          services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

then you can inject JSonAsClass inside any class you want to use it:

```
        private JSonAsClass jSonAsClass;
        public MailService(IOptions<JSonAsClass> jSonAsClass)
        {
            this.jSonAsClass = jSonAsClass.Value;
        }
```

Comment: this approach requires instantiation of the class, is there a way to do it with static methods?

Comment: I am not sure if you can find something similar to .net framework but it is a modern approach to read setting. By inject it you make your code easy to test and maintain.